# Joomla 3.3.6 subcategory title in category blog

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm working with Joomla 3.3.6 and I've been looking to achieve something like this:

**WHAT I HAVE**

category description

"article title1"         "article title2"         "article title3"

"article title4"         "article title5"         "article title6"

"article title7"         "article title8"         "article title9"

.......

**WHAT I WANT**

category description

SUBCATEGORY TITLE1
"article title1"         "article title2"         "article title3"

"article title4"         "article title5"         "article title6"

SUBCATEGORY TITLE2
"article title7"         "article title8"         "article title9"

.........

Can't find any extension, only found a workaround with modules, but it has some negative points.
Probably I've got to do a override! 
Note: I'm using the Nite yootheme template
How can I do this?
thanks in advance
**UPDATE - FOUND A SOLUTION**

1) follow the instructions on how to create a layout override in a yootheme template in this link: http://yootheme.com/themes/documentation/developers/customization where it says "LAYOUT OVERRIDES
2) becaus we're dealiing with the category blog, following the instructions in '1)' copy the blog.php file
3) open the file in a txt editor
4) search for this piece of code

```
if ($count = count($columns)) {
```

and right below it place this code:

```
$this->item = &$item;
$subcat = $this->item->category_title;
$articles  .= '<h3 class="uk-h3">'. $subcat .'</h3>';
```

that's it

Comment: Hi user1463905 Thank you for taking the time to provide the solution :) In keeping with JSE format, could you remove your update from the question above and add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a layout override is the best solution at component level.

**Component Alternative Layouts**
http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Component_Alternative_Layouts